# Alarm Manager doesn't trigger

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am developing an android application where I want to give my users the choice to set a time for notification and also if they want the notification re-sent after a specified interval. I am facing a problem with alarm manager. Somehow the alarm manager does not trigger the Broadcast receiver.

The following is the code for setting time for notification in alarm manager in main activity:

```
private void checkForCreatingNotification(Intent data){
    if (Constants.hours!=-1 && Constants.minutes!=-1){
        Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,Constants.hours);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,Constants.minutes);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        Log.e("time", " " + calendar.getTime());
        Log.e("time"," "+calendar.getTimeInMillis());

        boolean setOnce=data.getBooleanExtra(Constants.TIME_SET_ONCE,false);
        boolean setRepeat=data.getBooleanExtra(Constants.TIME_SET_REPEAT,false);
        int repeatDuration=data.getIntExtra(Constants.REPEAT_DURATION,Constants.NO_DURATION_REPEAT);

        SharedPreferences preferences=getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=preferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(Constants.TIME_SET_ONCE,setOnce);
        editor.putBoolean(Constants.TIME_SET_REPEAT, setRepeat);
        editor.putInt(Constants.REPEAT_DURATION, repeatDuration);
        editor.apply();

        Intent intent;
        intent = new Intent(this,NotificationMessage.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this,
                Constants.NOTIFICATION_REQUEST , intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        if (setOnce){
            am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        }else if (setRepeat){
            if(repeatDuration==Constants.HOURS24_DURATION)
                am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
            else if (repeatDuration==Constants.HOURS12_DURATION)
                am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_DAY, pendingIntent);
            else if (repeatDuration==Constants.HOURS6_DURATION)
                am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_DAY/2, pendingIntent);
            else if (repeatDuration==Constants.HOURS1_DURATION)
                am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR, pendingIntent);
            else if (repeatDuration==Constants.MINUTES30_DURATION)
                am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR, pendingIntent);
            else if (repeatDuration==Constants.MINUTES5_DURATION)
                am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR/6, pendingIntent);
            else if (repeatDuration==Constants.MINUTES1_DURATION)
                am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES/15, pendingIntent);
        }
        //sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

The BroadCastReceiver:

```
public class NotificationMessage extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                        .setContentTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.notification_title))
                        .setContentText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.notification_message));
        mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, WardrobeHome.class);
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(WardrobeHome.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(Constants.NOTIFICATION_REQUEST, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
    }

}
```

I have declared the receiver in the manifest file.

Answer (score 2):

use PendingIntent.getBroadcast instead of PendingIntent.getService and you are good to go

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Although this may answer the question, it's a good idea to include some code and an explanation to help the asker out. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.